# Java/Android: Having strange date parsing issue

Tags: java, android, date

I'm developing an android app using Eclipse and android version as API-15, (ICS).

I'm having a strange problem parsing string into date object. Here's my code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
String st = "1/1/1990 12:00:00 AM";

try {
    Date dt = df.parse( st );
        return dt;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
```

It keeps giving ParseException error. I've tried various combination of date strings but still they cannot be converted into date object.

Also my string is supposed to contain a date+time in UTC, so the new date object to be created would be in UTC.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I didn't get any exception. Its working for me. `Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1990` was the o/p

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. It should work. Sounds like problem with your device itself and not code. Did you try to run it on emulator? Please, give more information about your project: JAVA, min max version API .....   And post your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

your getting exception, because string which u parsing is not matching to the format which you have formatted, change date format to as mentioned below. its always recommendable to use two digit date or time format.

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

Answer (score 0):

Try to represent day of month and as two-digit numbers "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a". I have this code and it works fine for me:

```
SimpleDateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                     try {

                        date=dfm.parse(datestring);;
                    } catch (ParseException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've traced the issue. It was because of messed up imports. I removed all the imports and used the Eclipse's organize import function. Now its no longer giving errors.

I wonder what had been imported earlier that the code was being accepted by lint. I think there are two different libraries for handling date by Java and by Android. Now Ive got only Java libraries for date. Works fine.

Sorry for the trouble folks.